# Why Array initializer is not Allowed here? What is the problem

Tags: java, arrays, initializer

```
class Main {
    public static void main() {

        int[] array = new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5};

    }
}
```

Comment: you are basically doing it twice. try int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};

Comment: You're not supposed to give the array size when initializing with values.

Comment: If you check error in eclipse it directly says that  'Cannot define dimension expressions when an array initializer is provided'. Initialize it without size.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


            int[] array = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};

        }
}
```

You are currently declaring the size of the array twice, the above will work.